Seafront Metropolis
This is part 74 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
Today I have enjoyed the views over a seafront metropolis from the observation deck of its most iconic landmark. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

1. Alternative to 9, to complete a KQJT hand
2. Counterpart of the above, on Stack Exchange
3. Characteristic of the upper classes, in British parlance
4. Cheesemaking byproduct
5. Chinese legendary figure with the epithet "the Engineer"
6. Dumbbell or kettlebell, say
7. Either Y in WYSIWYG
8. Belonging to me and the above
9. Grandmaster Yi
10. Hairstyle with a single long braid
11. Stand in the above, perhaps
12. Judo rank below dan
13. Mine or the high one, as they say
14. The above, in Chinese philosophy
15. Neil Robertson's instrument
16. Number of legs for a brown recluse
17. Serve restaurant tables
18. Syllable used thrice when spelling out Canada, aptly enough
19. Term for a small island in the River Thames
20. The circumference of a unit circle
21. What the dog did to the homework, in a cliché
22. Word after after or business

Gladys will return in Compass and Straightedge.

Gladys is in

 the Kuwait Towers.

Let's solve the clues:

Alternative to 9, to complete a KQJT hand


 A


Counterpart of the above, on Stack Exchange


 Q


Characteristic of the upper classes, in British parlance


 U


Cheesemaking byproduct


 whey


Chinese legendary figure with the epithet "the Engineer"


 Yu


Dumbbell or kettlebell, say


 weight


Either Y in WYSIWYG


 you


Belonging to me and the above


 ours


Grandmaster Yi


 Wei


Hairstyle with a single long braid


 queue


Stand in the above, perhaps


 wait


Judo rank below dan


 kyū


Mine or the high one, as they say


 way


The above, in Chinese philosophy


 Tao


Neil Robertson's instrument


 cue


Number of legs for a brown recluse


 eight


Serve restaurant tables


 wait


Syllable used thrice when spelling out Canada, aptly enough


 eh


Term for a small island in the River Thames


 ait


The circumference of a unit circle


 tau


What the dog did to the homework, in a cliché


 ate


Word after after or business


 hours

Hm, a lot of these are kind of similar ...

 We can group them into homophones as follows:

 A eh
 Q queue kyū cue
 U Yu you
 whey Wei way
 weight wait wait
 ours hours
 Tao tau
 eight ait ate

Now, what in the world is that diagram?

 Well, there are eight groups of homophones, and eight boxes. Note too the numbers of circles in the boxes: one with 4, four with 3, and three with 2 - perfectly corresponding to the numbers of answers in each group. So, we can put the Q group in the upper left - but where to go from here? Well, the way the boxes are stacked on top of each other implies a relationship between them: maybe we're looking for something that sounds like "Q" but without the beginning sound - and of course, that's "U"!

 Extending this pattern, we can fill in the rest of the boxes as such:



To find the answer,

 simply read from left to right: Gladys must be in the Queue-Weight Taours! Er, sorry, I meant the Kuwait Towers!

Note also that

 there are three Kuwait Towers, matching the three stacks of boxes in the puzzle!

